# ERROR: could not open relation with OID 12303343

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql, dbeaver, pglogical

I am using cloudsql postgresql and have installed pglogical extension for logical replication between two data sources.

However when I run following command in Dbeaver client I get the errors

```
SELECT pglogical.replication_set_add_table(
    set_name := 'my_set', relation := 'public.table', 
    synchronize_data := TRUE
);


org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.sql.DBSQLException: SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: could not open relation with OID 12303343
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCStatementImpl.executeStatement(JDBCStatementImpl.java:133)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.executeStatement(SQLQueryJob.java:582)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.lambda$1(SQLQueryJob.java:491)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBExecUtils.tryExecuteRecover(DBExecUtils.java:189)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.executeSingleQuery(SQLQueryJob.java:498)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.extractData(SQLQueryJob.java:934)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.SQLEditor$QueryResultsContainer.readData(SQLEditor.java:3919)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetJobDataRead.lambda$0(ResultSetJobDataRead.java:123)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBExecUtils.tryExecuteRecover(DBExecUtils.java:189)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetJobDataRead.run(ResultSetJobDataRead.java:121)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetViewer$ResultSetDataPumpJob.run(ResultSetViewer.java:5101)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.runtime.AbstractJob.run(AbstractJob.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not open relation with OID 12303343
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2676)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2366)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:356)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:496)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:413)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:333)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:319)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:295)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:290)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCStatementImpl.execute(JDBCStatementImpl.java:330)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCStatementImpl.executeStatement(JDBCStatementImpl.java:131)
    ... 12 more
```

What could be the reason and how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

### Reconnect

Simply invalidate and reconnect with the database can solve this problem in DBeaver

[image]

### References :

https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/pglogical/issues/347